# Azure Datafactory Pipeline execution status

Tags: azure-data-factory

It is kind of annoying we cannot change the logical order(AND/OR) of the Activity dependencies. however, I have got another issue. having said that I have activities for on failure to log the error messages in DB, since the logging activity succeeds, the entire pipeline  succeeds too! is there any workaround to say if any activities failed the entire pipeline and the parent pipeline, if it is called from another pipeline, should be failed either?

In my screenshot, i have selected the on completion dependencies to log the successful or error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see that you defined "On Success" of the copy activity to run "usp_postexecution" . Please define a "On failure"  of the copy activity and add any activity ( may be a set variable for testing  ) and execute the pipeline . The pipeline will fail .

Just to give you more context what i tried .
I have a variable name "test" of the type boolean and I am failing it deliberately ( by assigning to a non-boolean value of true1 )

Pipeline will fail when I define both success and failure scenarios .

[image]

The pipeline will succeed  when you have only "Failure" defined

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the "usp_postexecution" logs the execution status in DB. and is upon the completion not success of the copy data. I wanted to log both success and failure in an activity. By the way since I already know the status,it is a parameter passed to the sp, I managed to fail the "usp_postexecution" activity manually after logging the status by raising error within the sp if status is Failure. in this case the pipeline will fail too.